# Mongo aggregation: partitioning values into groups

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is probably a longshot, but:

I'd like to group a set of time-series documents by gaps between dates: sort the documents ascending by date, then partition when the interval between the current and previous is above some threshold.

I can do this easily after getting the documents, of course; in this example, the original documents get a new partition number field:

```
// assuming sorted docs
var partition = 0;
var partitioned = docs.map((e,i) => {
        if(i > 0)
            if(e.date - docs[i-1].date > minInterval) partition++;

        return {
            date: e.date,
            partition: partition
        }
    });
```

But I don't actually need the documents themselves, I just need the first and last dates and number of docs for each partition. It's just unclear how I would do the partitioning function.

Is this possible with an aggregation? I see a [possibly relevant Mondo ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29161) that is open, so I'm guessing not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. To compare multiple documents you need to put them in one array using [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) and passing `null` as `_id`. Then to start comparing values you need an index just like in for loop so you can generate it using [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) operator.

To determine partitions you need double [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html). First one will return an array of `0` and `1` values where `1` means that this date starts new partition.

Second `$map` is to merge dates with partition indexes. To get the partition index you can [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html) an subarray ([$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)) of zeros and ones.

For instance:

```
db.col.save({ date: ISODate("2019-04-12T21:00:00.000Z") })
db.col.save({ date: ISODate("2019-04-12T21:15:00.000Z") })
db.col.save({ date: ISODate("2019-04-12T21:45:00.000Z") })
db.col.save({ date: ISODate("2019-04-12T23:00:00.000Z") })
db.col.save({ date: ISODate("2019-04-12T20:00:00.000Z") })
db.col.save({ date: ISODate("2019-04-12T18:30:00.000Z") })
db.col.save({ date: ISODate("2019-04-12T20:10:00.000Z") })
```

For the interval of `20` minutes you can run below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $sort: { date: 1 } },
    { $group: { _id: null, dates: { $push: "$date" } } },
    {
        $addFields: {
            partitions: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$dates" } ] },
                    as: "index",
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                current: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$dates", "$$index" ] },
                                prev: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$dates", { $add: [ "$$index", -1 ] } ] }
                            },
                            in: {
                                $cond: [
                                    { $or: [ { $eq: [ "$$index", 0 ] }, { $lt: [ { $subtract: [ "$$current", "$$prev" ] }, 1200000 ] } ] },
                                    0,
                                    1
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            datesWithPartitions: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$dates" } ] },
                    as: "index",
                    in: {
                        date: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$dates", "$$index" ] },
                        partition: { $sum: { $slice: [ "$partitions", { $add: [ "$$index", 1 ] } ] } }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

which wlll print:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "datesWithPartitions" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-04-12T18:30:00Z"),
            "partition" : 0
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-04-12T20:00:00Z"),
            "partition" : 1
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-04-12T20:10:00Z"),
            "partition" : 1
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-04-12T21:00:00Z"),
            "partition" : 2
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-04-12T21:15:00Z"),
            "partition" : 2
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-04-12T21:45:00Z"),
            "partition" : 3
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-04-12T23:00:00Z"),
            "partition" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

[MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WzGUTy7zph8)

Comment: Holy bejeebus that's amazing. OK. Is there any particular benefit to running this as a Mongo query as opposed to doing it in post?

Comment: @T3db0t I think the answer show that it's possible :-) To decide whether it's better to do that in Mongo or in BL you'd have to run some perf tests on your data set.

Comment: OK, let me up the ante—how would I project the results to be the partitions themselves? so: `[{startDate:__, endDate:___, numItems: 5}, etc]

Comment: @T3db0t not sure if I understand you correctly, could you open another question and link it here ? I will try to take a look

Comment: OK, I posted this variant with example output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797685/mongo-aggregation-partitioning-values-into-groups-by-partition